# PHP switch statement "echoing" the wrong case

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
$year = readline('Type your year of birth: ');

$age = 2023 - $year;

switch ($age) {
    case ($age < 0):
    echo 'I don't see in the future.';
    break;
    case ($age >= 0) && ($age <= 3):
    echo 'Congrats. A newborn capable of using the PC.';
    break;
    case ($age > 3):
    echo 'Our system calculated that you are:' . ' ' . $age . ' ' . 'years old';
    break;
}
```

So this is from my first lesson of PHP and the statement "echoes" the first case if I input 2023 but it should echo the second one. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Easiest way to start debugging is to echo $age before your switch statement and see what that variable is

Comment: @KosyOnyenso I've already done that. It's 0 and it should echo 'Congrats.. etc'

Comment: There's a syntax error in this code, not sure how you're getting any output.

Comment: @frengo- please try the answer I just gave

Comment: Assuming the quote syntax error is a typo (and fixed), then as to why when `$age == 0` falls into the case `$age < 0` it is due to [loose comparisons](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) between `0` and `false` which the switch statement [employs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Comment: It's very confusing to use `switch()` here. A simple set of `if()` and `elseif()` would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `switch ($age)` to `switch (true)`.
Try this:

```
switch (true) {
    case ($age < 0):
    echo "I don't see in the future.";
    break;
    case ($age >= 0) && ($age <= 3):
    echo "Congrats. A newborn capable of using the PC.";
    break;
    case ($age > 3):
    echo "Our system calculated that you are:" . " " . $age . " " . "years old";
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`case`s are values, not expressions to evaluate. It looks like you meant to use an if-else:

```php
if ($age < 0) {
    echo 'I don\'t see in the future.';
} elseif ($age >= 0) && ($age <= 3) {
    echo 'Congrats. A newborn capable of using the PC.';
} else if ($age > 3) { # Could have also been an "else", without the condition
    echo 'Our system calculated that you are:' . ' ' . $age . ' ' . 'years old';
}
```